# error org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed] on centos 7

Tags: centos, pentaho, etl, pdi

I am new in centos 7, I Install Pentaho PDI 7 and  run ./spoon.sh in centos 7 and this error pop Up :

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:642)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
```

I've install Java 1.8. It's anything I missed to install?
Please help.

Comment: Check the solution from the [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94497/org-eclipse-swt-swterror-no-more-handles-gtk-init-check-failed-while-runnin)

Comment: Thanks for the link Egor. I can open spoon.sh now, but why the responsive is so slow? do you have any idea? thanks

Comment: When I run with Xvfb, pentaho shows ```Graphics2D from BufferedImage lacks BUFFERED_IMAGE hint```. How can I see the GUI from remote windows server ? I'm using the ubuntu, where pentaho is running, by using ssh

Answer (score 2):

Same pb here, I've managed to make it work installing xvfb (centos 6)

Comment: Hi, thanks. Finally I've managed the display using x11. but why is soo slow?

Comment: slowness can have multiple reasons, depends on your hardware and os and application currently running plus your "user feeling"... what do you mean by slow ?

Comment: I've run pentaho by using Xvfb in DISPLAY:=1, but I'm working on Windows and I'm connecting the ubuntu by using ssh. How can I see the gui from windows ? @k4cy

Answer (score 0):

Fixed mine by issuing the follows.

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similour error message and the reason was the inability to reach a X11 server.

Check if you have a valid X11 server reachable by you application. Look at the DISPLAY environment variable.

Answer (score -1):

'If you are running on a linux with Gnome:

Start a Gnome with an Xorg session:

After clicking your username in GDM (the greeter/login manager), click your username and before entering the password, click the little gear and select 'Gnome with Xorg', then enter your password